# How do i change the font in my text editor from the font menu

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.filedialog
from tkinter import ttk

class TextEditor:

    @staticmethod
    def quit_app(event=None):
        root.quit()

    def change_font(self, event=None):
        print(text_font.get())

    def open_file(self, event=None):

        txt_file = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=root, initialdir="C:/Users/Cesar/PycharmProjects")

        if txt_file:
            self.text_area.delete(1.0, END)

            with open(txt_file) as _file:
                self.text_area.insert(1.0, _file.read())

                root.updata_idletasks()

    def save_file(self, event=None):

        file = tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w')

        if file != None:
            data = self.text_area.get(1.0, END + '-1c')
            file.write(data)
            file.close()

    def __init__(self, root):

        self.text_to_write = ""

        root.title("Text Editor")

        root.geometry("600x500")

        frame = Frame(root, width=600, height=500)

        scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame)

        self.text_area = Text(frame, width=600, height=500, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set, padx=10, pady=10)

        scrollbar.config(command=self.text_area.yview)

        scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill="y")

        self.text_area.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

        frame.pack()

        the_menu = Menu(root)

        # ---------- file menu -------------

        file_menu = Menu(the_menu, tearoff=0)

        file_menu.add_command(label="Open",command=self.open_file)

        file_menu.add_command(label="Save", command=self.save_file)

        file_menu.add_separator()

        file_menu.add_command(label="Quit", command=self.quit_app())

        the_menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)

        # ---------- format menu and font menu--------
        """ 

        font_menu = Menu(the_menu, tearoff=0)

        text_font = StringVar()
        text_font.set("Times")

        def change_font():
            style = ttk.Style()
            style.configure(self.text_area, font = text_font)
            print("Font picked: ", text_font.get())

        font_menu = Menu(the_menu, tearoff=0)

        font_menu.add_radiobutton(label="Times", variable=text_font, command=change_font)

        font_menu.add_radiobutton(label="Arial", variable=text_font, command=change_font)

        font_menu.add_radiobutton(label="Consoles", variable=text_font, command=change_font)

        font_menu.add_radiobutton(label="Courier", variable=text_font, command=change_font)

        font_menu.add_radiobutton(label="Tahoma", variable=text_font, command=change_font)

        the_menu.add_cascade(label="Fonts", menu=font_menu)

        """

        root.config(menu=the_menu)

root = Tk()

text_edit = TextEditor(root)

root.mainloop()
```

i put the code for the font menu in a comment to make sure the program is working

Comment: Dangit, why these workarounds? Flagged for poor formatting. Also, you didn't explain your problem, and do research.

Comment: You've posted a lot of irrelevant code. See How to create a [mcve]. Readability could also be improved if you didn't have blank lines between most of your code.

Answer (score 0):

`ttk.Style` is used to style objects from ttk, which `Text` is not. To set the font on a `tkinter.Text` widget you need to use `tkinter.font.Font`.

```
import tkinter.font
#...
def __init__(self):
    # ...
    # ---------- format menu and font menu--------

    self.text_font = StringVar()
    self.text_font.set("Times")

    font_menu = Menu(the_menu, tearoff=0)
    self.fonts = {}
    for font in ("Times","Arial", "Consoles", "Courier", "Tahoma"):
        self.fonts[font] = tkinter.font.Font(font=font)
        font_menu.add_radiobutton(label=font, variable=self.text_font, command=self.change_font)

    the_menu.add_cascade(label="Fonts", menu=font_menu)

    root.config(menu=the_menu)

def change_font(self):
    self.text_area.config(font = self.fonts[self.text_font.get()])
```

BTW a scrolled Text widget is built into tkinter in the ScrolledText widget.